# jQuery links not clickable but i can right click open in new tab?

Tags: jquery, list, hyperlink, html-lists

I am having so much trouble with this site! http://pearsonlyle.uwpistol.net/galleries/susie-theodorou/editorial/

The navigation that is visible doesn't click, but i can right click and open in new tab. The list is cloned li's based on the selected sub nav.

```
var subNavParent = $('ul li ul li ul li.selected').parent().parent();
    var subNav = $('ul li ul li ul li.selected').siblings();



    $("<ul class='horizontal-sub-nav-ul'></ul>").appendTo(".header");

    $(subNavParent).clone().appendTo('.horizontal-sub-nav-ul');//grandparent
    $('ul li ul li ul li.selected').clone().appendTo('.horizontal-sub-nav-ul');//siblings

    $(subNav).clone().appendTo('.horizontal-sub-nav-ul');//this
```

Very irritating!

Anyone have any ideas? Could do with a second, third, fourth and seventh pair of eyes I think!

Comment: I'm assuming this is an anchor tag since you can right click and open.  Sounds like you have a click handler for the anchor tag that is either cancelling the event or experiencing an error.  Can you post the links and click handler(s)?  Some of us aren't brave enough to open untrusted links... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something in file `menus.js`, method `initMenuStylists` attach click handler on top menu (`Photographers` and `Stylists`), but that method fires on click on the one of `Commercial`, `Editoral` and `Showreel` links!

EDITED

Found it!
Code in `menus.js` that begins from line 122 makes `event.preventDefault()` for many `<a>` elements. And also for elements that using for creating your not-working menu with cloning.

Comment: event.preventDefault() prevents default action on link thus no page loading happens. But middle-button click working because this behavior attached only on click.

Comment: Thanks so much that was the answer!!! You rock! I just moved the event.preventDefault() to after the cloning of the menu's and it's working!!